# How to make ListView take only as much space as it needs in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a simple case, this is my layout:

```
  ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: [
       Text("Row 1"),
       Text("Row 2")
    ],
  )
```

I want it to take only **as much space in horizontal plane as its child widgets**. Unfortunately, it expands to the whole width of the screen, which is the [default behaviour](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints) of ListView.
Is there any way to make it take only as much space as necessary? The equivalent for Android would be `wrap_content`.

There are a lot of similar questions on this topic, but usually they are really looking for an *alignment* (so content aligned within their boundaries), whereas I'm looking for rows not taking all width (so having as small boundaries as possible).

Also I don't want to limit the size to some precise number, I want it to be flexible depending on the children width.

Comment: One solution is to replace `ListView` with `Column` for vertilcal list and `Row` for horizonal list. For scrolling use `SingleChildScrollView` as parent. There is mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment for both row and column for adjusting the children. Also, `IntrinsicWidth` and `IntrinsicHeight` allow children to be equally sized. Do you need a sample code?

Comment: Thanks Doc, would that mean that I just build the list of widgets myself? I.e. instead of passing children to `ListView`, I would just list these children in column (for vertical list)? What would be the drawback of that approach compared to using `ListView`? `ListView` just seems like a natural approach coming from Android background.

Comment: Passing list works just as well as explicitly specifying them or using a map function. The only drawback here is `ListView` is optimised as it has lazy evaluation of children rather than eager one for the aproach I suggested. The other way is to have `Expanded` with flex on the `ListView` along with other expanded sibling in the parent inside a Row or Column as super parent. In this way you get lazy evaluation of `ListView` with it taking as much space as needed.

Comment: That makes sense, feel free to add it as a response, surely will be helpful as a reference in the future. I will wait a few days before I mark it as accepted as maybe there is some way to do it directly with ListView. But I tried your way and it's actually pretty simple. Thanks :)